# Joomla 2.5 API Key error "This page does not load Google Maps correctly"

Tags: joomla

I entered the billing information in my Google Cloud Platform account but the generated API key does not work on my [Joomla 2.5.8 site](http://www.pegasusimmobili.it/gli-immobili/casali/1032-714-casale-candigliano) with the included googlemap2 plugin. The message that appears on the map is: "This page does not load Google Maps correctly".

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typically entering your billing information should fix any problem you have with maps. If it doesn't, then the problem is usually with the extension - if updating the extension doesn't fix it (or is not possible, because of your old Joomla site), then your 2 options are to: 1) update your Joomla website to the latest version (3.8.13 as of the time of writing this) or 2) modify the code in your maps extension to address the problem.

Comment: Thanks Itoctopus, do you know someone who can help me make the second option?